# Dojo: how to use own onMove event (overwrite)

Tags: javascript, events, dojo

In docs it was said that:

onMove(mover, leftTop, e) called during every move notification; should actually move the node; can be overwritten.

but no example how to overwrite it (onMove). Can somebody throw several lines of code to show how it works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't point out which dojo JavaScript class that the `onMove` function belongs to. However, you have a couple of generic ways to override functions that also applies in your case.

1) Create a new subclass using [`dojo.declare`](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/declare).

Suppose the JavaScript class name is `myClass`, you can use

```
dojo.declare('anotherClass', myClass, {
    onMove : function(mover, leftTop, e) {}   
});
```

2) Change the class's prototype using [`dojo.extend`](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/extend).

```
dojo.extend(myClass, {
    onMove : function(mover, leftTop, e) {}         
});
```

If you only want to override the function for a single instance, set the property directly.

```
var obj = new myClass();
obj.onMove = function() {};
```