# How to override dojo combox.js methods

Tags: javascript, dojo

I would like to override one method

```
onMouseUp:function(evt){
if(evt.target===this.domNode||!this._highlighted_option){
return;
}else{
if(evt.target==this.previousButton){
this.onPage(-1);
}else{
if(evt.target==this.nextButton){
this.onPage(1);
}else{
var tgt=evt.target;
while(!tgt.item){
tgt=tgt.parentNode;
}
```

in my JavaScript file.

How can I do that?

Comment: What widget are you talking about ? What is dojo combox.js ? Did you mean dijit.form.ComboBox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally, overwrite it using the same object and same method name.

```
var object = {
    'method': function() {
        // original script
    }
};

// your script

object.method = function() {
    // your script, original gets overwritten
};
```

---

**EDIT**

After a quick google and clicking the first result, I found a very simular thread which is probably more accurate for your... "problem": [Dojo: how to use own onMove event (overwrite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508571/dojo-how-to-use-own-onmove-event-overwrite)